# How do I add a CycleTile tile using c# on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have the following code for adding a tile on Windows Phone 8 but I can't get the tile to show.

```
CycleTileData cycletile = new CycleTileData();
cycletile.Title = "Test";
cycletile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri(root.data[0].user.profile_picture,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the tile to the start screen using [ShellTile.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207966%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).  Setting the CycleImages property couldn't hurt either.

```
List<Uri> list = [your image list];
Uri smallImage = [your image];

CycleTileData tileData = new CycleTileData() 
{ 
    Title = group.Title, 
    SmallBackgroundImage = smallImage
    CycleImages = list 
 }; 

 ShellTile.Create(new Uri(NavSource, UriKind.Relative), tileData, true);
```

There are lots of samples on [Microsoft Dev Center](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-8-JumpStart-2b8a0d79/sourcecode?fileId=73381&pathId=719636597) or [Windows Phone Geek](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/live-tiles-in-windows-phone-8-part-1-tile-templates)